# Using sympy to rearrange an expression

Tags: python, sympy

I am attempting to solve for a variable (T_p) in terms of another (T_i) using sympy. However all that is returned after running is empty square brackets i.e [].
My current code is as follows:

```
from sympy import *
T_i, T_p = symbols('T_i T_p')
eq = Eq(1.32*(T_i - T_p)**1.25 + 58.5*T_i, 3774)
sol = (solve(eq, T_p))
print(sol)
```

I am unsure what is wrong as it has worked for other equations. Any help would be appreciated.
Could it be that the solve function doesn't like fractional powers? If so, is there a similar function that does?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. With sympy 1.8 there 5 solutions, starting with `T_p = T_i - 582.079590294065*(1 - 0.0155007949125596*T_i)**(4/5)`

Comment: @JohanC I'm not getting any solutions for 1.9

Comment: Indeed. Upgrading to sympy 1.9 gives an empty solution. And `solve(eq)` gives an error: `NotImplementedError: No algorithms are implemented to solve equation 117*T_i/2 + 33*(T_i - T_p)**(5/4)/25 - 3774`

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like a symbolic quintic?

Comment: Inside `solvers.solvers.unrad`, the code has changed slightly and somewhere along the line, the variable `poly` is of a different syntactic form but both are equivalent. This different form results in different treatment. Try running `unrad(2925*T_i + 66*(T_i - T_p)**(5/4) - 188700, T_p)` in both versions.

Comment: @smichr Seems like #21276 caused the change in behavior but I could be wrong. `gens` seems to be different because `_take` has changed as well.

Comment: I will take a look more closely, thanks. I'll open an issue.

Comment: issue opened: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/22584